# Locking sub-directories from the view of certain users

Tags: security, ftp

I have certain sub-dirs that I do not want certain developers to have access to when they login via FTP. They need to view most files/dirs, but some are off limits. Is there any way to block viewing these sub-directories by certain users when they login via FTP but not prevent PHP and Apache from including required files?

This is a Linux server that runs cPanel and WHM.

Comment: Did you just say "I have root Telnet access" on Serverfault? OMFG

Comment: Can you uh, provide the IP of this telnet server?

Comment: As much as I'd absolutely love to...no, sorry, can't. I have the firewall white listed to my IP only anyway.

Comment: This might be answerable if you included what FTP software you are using and the directory structure and user permissions you desire.  It might be significantly better to *change* your directory structure so that this problem becomes an easy one to solve.

Comment: In the end, that turned out to be the most effective way to go!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can do this. Use standard [POSIX permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).

Comment: And this can be set to only affect FTP users but leave access available to web users accessing a specific script?

Comment: The web services accessing these directories are running under the same user context as the FTP users?

Comment: They shouldn't be. FTP always requires a login/pass and an Apache served page does not.

Comment: Then of course you can restrict this. Use POSIX permissions to only allow specific users to those directories and make sure the specific web service users are in the allowed groups...